# Powershell: Can someone help me understand what I need to do to prevent this error?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've got a script that I'm running where I declare the path I'm using, then define my source files as all the child items in that path.

```
$htmPath = "c:\users\x\desktop\cgc\ht"
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "*.htm*"
```

I've run this successfully in the past, but this morning I started getting the following error:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '*' operator.
At C:\users\x\desktop\cgc\CGC002.PS1:63 char:46
+ $srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "* <<<< .htm*"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

To me, it appears that this error is being thrown because the script is interpreting my wildcard as a multiplication, and wants the value on the right side necessary to complete the operation. Am I interpreting it properly? If that is indeed the case, how do I make sure that my wildcard is interpreted as a widlcard?

I *did* find [this link](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/9036.aspx), but it's a different enough scenario with different enough code that I'm not sure it applies. However, I did find this comment in the thread interesting:

**Try putting the *, at the start of the property list instead of the end. I think it's just getting confused. It's mainly your formatting.**

...so I exited PS, warm-booted, the usual did-you-try-turning-it-off-and-back-on-again confusion resetters, and still, the same error.

Maybe I have a typo somewhere that I can't see?

Or, if I'm completely missing the interpretation of the error...school me.

Comment: Have you tried using a variable for `"*.htm*"`?

Comment: @entonio - I have...same error.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Try without double quote...  just `*.htm`... you can avoid last `*`

Comment: That error sounds like you have, somewhat earlier in the script, an unmatched double quote; so the parser is seeing `"*.htm"` as the end of a string followed by `*.htm` (and then stopped). Try opening the script in ISE (or other editor with syntax highlighting for PSH).

Comment: I tried the lines of script you gave in a .ps1 file and it works smooth in PS v2.0 console. Hope you are using the same version. Try opening it with PowerShell ISE and see if there is any syntax error in your whole script or even you can use PowerGUI for a better experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a single double-quote off the right side of my text editor. Color coded syntax checking helped me verify that it was a mismatched quote issue...thinking to scroll to the right to FIND the `"` took a lot more time than it should have. Facepalm.

Thanks to @Richard who offered up this suggestion.